# LocalStorage Handling - How do we validate if user modfies from different browser or other machine?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Here is the case

1) User ( on his personal computer at home )  is trying to modify his post and for this we load his already saved content from database to browser in editable mode ( Editing his own post ) . He made changes to his post and for every key stoke we are storing his data in LocalStorage . After modifying bit of it he closed his browser ( with out saving the data to database ) .

2) The same user from different computer ( could be from office computer ) or from different browser 
he opened the same above post for editing and he sees his old content ( since he didn't save his posting ) . He made some changes and saved the content .

3) Back to home he wants to modify the same post again and opens it but this time he gets the data from his LocalStorage the one he edited in the first step .  This is totally invalid data . Since already he modified the content in the second step .

Could you please throw me some idea how do we delete his data modified in the first step or how do we proceed in this kind of scenarios ?

One thought I have is in the 1st step along with the data in the LocalStorage also store "time stamp" of the key strokes.  When loading the data from database again check the saved timestamp in the database with the timestamp in the local store . If it is less than the server time delete the LocalStorage key for that post . But is there any other easy way to handle it ?

Thank You

Comment: That could be his entry in the forum or his existing blog entry or his own editorial ( any data ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the problem by adding an entry key for localstorage in database for a user and post . If it is modified from other computer , the keys gets modified and so the entry in first computer gets invalidated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that at every load from DB, you first repopulate the localstorage after wiping out whatever value exists for the key ( I assume that you don't want the invalid data for anything. Only the latest saved data from the DB is required, right?).. Now if there are any changes from the client, the localstorage needs to be updated and read from.

If he opens the app from another machine, make sure you do the same there.

Basically, to prevent data corruption, always read from the DB first and localstorage later upon page load/AJAX call.  Client side data can always be manipulated, as you must know already.

Comment: what about if the client, in two different moments, alters in different ways the same data in two different, offline devices?

Comment: If you want to support offline modes, then some sort of validation is required to prevent bad data. If localstorage is going to be used for offline support, OP would need to confirm with the user(when the app comes online), which value needs to be used (DB or client side). Either way, I would assume that whichever instance gets online quicker would persist the data into the DB and that data would reflect. Morever its always nice to use something like a session id, to make the key unique. Not sure if OP wants offline support.

Comment: I am sorry I am confused @imguru . If user always loads from the database then there is no use of LocalStorage in this case .

Comment: I was talking about a situation where you make client side changes a value fetched from a DB, and wanna keep the change upon refresh/browser close and eventually want to persist back into the DB. If you want to capture local changes while in offline mode, I'm afraid what I said won't be valid.

Comment: sorry what I meant was if user gets it from DB obviously for refresh/browses close also gets it from database . So no where LocalStorage coming in to the picture here .